# Angular search a key in an object and change the value of another key

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this data below.
I need to be able to search in the objet for the id or name key and then change the 'show' key to a different value.
How example:

Search the data for id value 2 and change the show value to false.

```
data = [
   {
      id: 1,
      name: 'one',
      show: false;
      title: 'title1',
      data: [
         {
            id: 1,
            description: 'some description'
         },
         {
            id: 2,
            description: 'some other description'
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      name: 'two',
      show: true;
      title: 'title2',
      data: [
         {
            id: 1,
            description: 'some description'
         },
         {
            id: 2,
            description: 'some other description'
         }
       ]
    }
 ]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I can't find anything in google so I don't know where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `findIndex` method, and then access your array using the found Index and change any property you want, here's some code that match your use case

```
let index = data.findIndex((x) => x.id == THE_ID_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR);
if(index > -1) {
  data[index].show = THE_VALUE_YOU_WANT;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use normal array find method.

```
let item = data.find(x=>x.id===REQUIRED_ID);
if(item) item.show = false
```